# German stemming with SnowballPorterFilterFactory

Tags: java, solr, lucene, hibernate-search, snowballanalyzer

I have a problem with my german stemming SnowballPorterFilterFactory. I just can´t get it to work. Neither in english or germna. I´m using this AnalzyderDef.

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "customAnalyzer", charFilters = {
@CharFilterDef(factory = HTMLStripCharFilterFactory.class)},
            tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
            filters = {
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = TrimFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class, params = {
            @Parameter(name = "language", value = "German2")
        }),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = WordDelimiterFilterFactory.class, params = {
            @Parameter(name = "splitOnCaseChange", value = "1"),
            @Parameter(name = "splitOnNumerics", value = "1"),
            @Parameter(name = "generateWordParts", value = "1"),
            @Parameter(name = "preserveOriginal", value = "1")

        }),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class, params = {
            @Parameter(name = "minGramSize", value = "5"),
            @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "15"),
            @Parameter(name = "side", value = "front")
        })
            }))
```

I tried it with walk / walking / walks like mentioned [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#CharFilterFactories).
Is maybe the combination of the filters the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you try it with actual german words? And be sure to look at the tokens and not the text returned from the field (which will be identical to the stored one). Search for the stemmed version of a german word, and see if that changes. Use the analysis page under the Solr Admin interface to see how the tokens are generated and the text is processed for the field.

Comment: When you say "can't get it to work", what does that mean exactly? How are you using the configured analyzers, what outcome is it you expect and what happens instead?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It looks like you can´t use the Ngram filter including word stemming.

I removed the NGRAM Filter and not it works.